# JSON without sorting swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsdictionary

i am trying load data from JSON file. While loading it changes order when it is converted to NSDictionary. Is there any way to get the data in the same order as in JSON file. Please guide me.

Comment: Use an array if you want ordered data.

Comment: A dictionary does not have an order, it is just a collection of keys and values. You need to either sort the keys or sort the values yourself. Without any example code or a better statement of what you are trying to solve, we cannot give you much help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the data in a specific order, don't use a dictionary in your json. Use an array instead.

A dictionary is not an ordered collection. Saying it is in a different order makes no sense. It is not in any order.

An array is an ordered collection.

If you are not able to change the json then you should sort the keys and values and create a sorted array based on them yourself. It all depends what the keys and values are in your dictionary.

Comment: and if you don't have control of the json, you'll have to do what @keithbhunter describes.

Comment: Yes true. Will edit.